# UISegmentedControl setImage: or setText: not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a UISegmentedControl within a view both within a xib. In my app delegate I am creating the controller which is the file's owner of the xib using initWithNibName: and then wrapping it within a navigation controller (UINavigationController initWithRootViewController).

Then I try to set either the image or title of elements within the segmented control like this:

```
[self.viewController.segmentControl setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"some_image.png"]forSegmentAtIndex: 3];
[self.viewController.segmentControl setTitle: @"some text" forSegmentAtIndex: 2];
```

The segmented control is appearing but the setImage: and setTitle: is having no effect.
The first two cells say First and Second respectively which are the default values assigned when initially drag/dropping it within IB.

segmentControl is an IBOutlet and I've confirmed its connected to the segmented control.

Why is it not working?

I can set the image or text in IB and it works, but I would like to understand why I cannot set them programatically.

(The segmented control has 6 indexes).

Comment: Did you NSLog `self.viewController.segmentControl` to confirm (where it matters most) that it's not nil?

Comment: Its not being created - I thought everything in the nib would be created when initWithNibName: is called? If its nil when I examine it in the delegate, then how is it being displayed?

Comment: Not sure it's not being created so as much as the ivar/property is not getting set. I can't really help with the IB stuff; I don't use it so I've forgotten how to use it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you setting up the segmented control in your app delegate? Shouldn't you be adjusting it's attributes in the file's owner (viewController)? I would probably do this in viewController's viewDidLoad method, or since you're using IB anyway, simply set the image and title attributes there (in your XIB).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
[segmentControl setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"some_image.png"]forSegmentAtIndex: 3];
[segmentControl setTitle: @"some text" forSegmentAtIndex: 2];
```